# How do I echo strings on the same line as a previous echo?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I echo "I have 1 number" using two echo commands in a batch file?

```
echo "I have "
...
... do stuff
...
echo "1 number"
```

creates two lines:

```
I have
1 number
```

how do I suppress the cr/lf on the first echo?  to create:

```
I have 1 number
```

Comment: Using echo you can't. To print to screen without a cr/lf use `set /P "dummy=I have "<NUL` and later on `echo 1 number`

Comment: …or you `Set "Prn2Scr=I have " & Echo(%Prn2Scr%` …then later `Set "Prn2Scr=%Prn2Scr%1 number" & Echo(%Prn2Scr%`. Your question however is vague, supressing the CRLF should leave you with `"I have ""1 number"`.

Comment: Your code would also output the enclosing `""`...

Answer (score 1):

this appears to do it:

```
<nul set /p=I have 
echo 1 number
```

note that this example is too simplistic- in a more general case the second part is not just an echo but the result of some calculation or manipulation, for example cd:

```
<nul set /p=set currentdir=>a.bat
cd>>a.bat
```

I can't see that this functionality is possible with the PART1 answer given above.

Comment: Remove the word `echo` from the first line of code... You may use quotes for the first line to indicate the trailing space: `set /P ="I have "`...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing part of the problem. Save the first part in a variable, then use it later with the latter part.

```
SET "PART_1=I have "
.
... do stuff
.
ECHO %PART_1% 1 number
```

How about...

```
C:\Users\lit\t>ECHO SET "currentdir=%CD%" >a.bat

C:\Users\lit\t>type a.bat
SET "currentdir=C:\Users\lit\t"
```

Multiple lines...? The ECHO command writes a newline CRLF at the end of anything it outputs. You are not going to get a subsequent ECHO command to write over the newline from the first ECHO. How about...

```
SET TMPFILE=%TEMP%\mytempfile.tmp
ECHO>"%TMPFILE%" I have
... do stuff
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`TYPE "%TMPFILE%"`) DO (SET "S1=%%~a")
ECHO %S1% 1 file
IF EXIST "%TMPFILE%" (DEL "%TMPFILE%")
```

Comment: my example is too simplistic- see my edit of my answer

Comment: that's all done on one line, I was asking about multiline use

Comment: I think the solution below is much simpler!